# Android: Matrix -> what is the different between preconcat and postconcat?

Tags: android, matrix

I'm using [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to scale and rotate Bitmaps. Now I'm wondering what the difference between preconcat & postconcat is, or more precisely the difference between:

- [postRotate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#postRotate(float))
- [preRotate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#preRotate(float))
- [setRotate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#setRotate(float))

From what I could figure out so far setRotate always overwrites the whole matrix, while with preRotate and postRotate I can apply multiple changes to a matrix (e.g. scaling + rotation). However, either using postRotate or preRotate didn't cause any different results for the cases I used them.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The answer to your question isn't really specific to Android; it's a graphics and math question. There's lots of theory in this answer--you've been warned! For a superficial answer to your question, skip to the bottom. Also, because this is such a long-winded tirade, I might have a typo or two making things unclear. I apologize in advance if that's the case.

In computer graphics, we can represent pixels (or in 3D, vertices) as vectors. If your screen is 640x480, here's a 2D vector for the point in the middle of your screen (forgive my shoddy markup):

```
[320]
[240]
[  1]
```

I'll explain why the 1 is important later. Transformations are often represented using [matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)) because it's then very simple (and very efficient) to chain them together, like you mentioned. To scale the point above by a factor of 1.5, you can [left-multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) it by the following matrix:

```
[1.5   0   0]
[  0 1.5   0]
[  0   0   1]
```

You'll get this new point:

```
[480]
[360]
[  1]
```

Which represents the original point, scaled by 1.5 relative to the corner of your screen (0, 0). This is important: scaling is always done with respect to the origin. If you want to scale with some other point as your center (such as the middle of a sprite), you need to "wrap" the scale in translations to and from the origin. Here's the matrix to translate our original point to the origin:

```
[1  0  -320]
[0  1  -240]
[0  0     1]
```

Which yields:

```
[320*1 + 1*-320]   [0]
[240*1 + 1*-240] = [0]
[     1*1      ]   [1]
```

You'll recognize the above as the [identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) matrix with the displacement coordinates slapped in the upper-right corner. That's why the 1 (the "homogenous coordinate") is necessary: to make room for these coordinates, thus making it possible to translate using multiplication. Otherwise it would have to be represented by matrix addition, which is more intuitive to humans, but would make graphics cards even more complicated than they already are.

Now, matrix multiplication generally [isn't commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties), so when "adding" a transformation (by *multiplying* your matrix) you need to specify whether you're left-multiplying or right-multiplying. The difference it makes is what order your transformations are chained in. By right-multiplying your matrix (using `preRotate()`) you're indicating that the rotation step should happen *before* all the other transformations that you've just asked for. This might be what you want, but it usually isn't.

Often, it doesn't matter. If you only have one transformation, for example, it never matters :) Sometimes, your transformations can happen in either order with the same effect, such as scaling and rotation--my linear algebra is rusty, but I believe that in this case the matrix multiplication actually is commutative because the scale matrix is [symmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix), that is, it mirrors itself across the diagonal. But really, just think about it: If I rotate some picture 10 degrees clockwise and then scale it to 200%, it looks the same as if I scaled it first, then rotated it.

If you were doing some weirder compound transformations, you'd begin to notice a discrepancy. My advice is to stick with `postRotate()`.

Comment: Per the docs,
M.preConcat(other)  > M' = M * other,
M.postConcat(other) > M' = other * M,
I'm currently trying some of this out but it seems that 'pre' sets the new operation after the ones you've already done, and 'post' does it before. I'm scaling then translating, it needs to scale and then translate because the translation is in scaled coordinates. It works if I 'pre' but not if i 'post'. This notation is confusing to me, so let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: I had to double- and triple-take the docs, as well. The naming scheme is rather confusing, so I might have gotten it backwards. I'm not sure I understand *your* notation, though :) 

`other*M` is a left-multiply, and should yield `M`'s transformations followed by `other`'s. I think.

Comment: I got that notation from here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html#preConcat(android.graphics.Matrix) I also find the naming confusing.

Comment: love concise and in-depth explanations! +1.

Comment: @Cheezmeister can you suggest some source where I can find more on computer graphics , explained in depth like your answer

Comment: Glad you found it helpful. Offhand, I know the arcsynthesis tutorial set (google it) is quite thorough, albeit OpenGL-oriented; or find an intro-level [MOOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) in graphics.

Answer (score 6):

I answered the question yesterday， but  I feel sometiong wrong today ,So I correct the answer here:

```
matrix:  float[] values ={1.2f,0.5f,30,0.5f,1.2f,30,0,0,1};

//as we all know, the basic value in matrix,means no transformation added
matrix2:  float[] values2 ={1f,0,0,0,1f,0,0,0,1};

Let's say our matrix values are the values above.
```

1、  when we do the transformation like below:

```
matrix.preTranslate(-50, -50);

is equals to do sequence transformation to matrix2 above like below:

matrix2.postTranslate(-50, -50);
matrix2.postSkew(0.5f/1.2f,0.5f/1.2f);// note here
matrix2.postScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
matrix2.postTranslate(30, 30);
```

2、   when we do the transformation like below :

```
matrix.preRotate(50);

is equals to do sequence transformation to matrix2 like below:

matrix2.postRotate(50);
matrix2.postSkew(0.5f/1.2f,0.5f/1.2f);
matrix2.postScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
matrix2.postTranslate(30, 30);
```

3、   when we do the transformation like below :

```
matrix.preScale(1.3f,1.3f);

is equals to do sequence transformation to matrix2 like below:

matrix2.postScale(1.3f,1.3f);
matrix2.postSkew(0.5f/1.2f,0.5f/1.2f);
matrix2.postScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
matrix2.postTranslate(30, 30);
```

4、  when we do the transformation like below :

```
 matrix.preSkew(0.4f,0.4f);
```

is equals to do sequence transformation to matrix2 like below:

```
 matrix2.postSkew(0.4f,0.4f);
 matrix2.postSkew(0.5f/1.2f,0.5f/1.2f);
 matrix2.postScale(1.2f, 1.2f);
 matrix2.postTranslate(30, 30);
```