# Issue with Canvas.rotate() in Android .How does it exactly work?

Tags: android, graphics, canvas, 2d

Please find the code of my onDraw method below(.I'm trying to rotate the canvas(//Rotate call -b) by 25 degrees after drawing the arc .But i find that the arc is still drawn from 0 to 50 degrees.I was expecting it to move by another 25 degrees.

```
public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

    }
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            int px = getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
            int py = getMeasuredHeight() / 2;

            // radius - min 
            int radius = 130;

            // Defining bounds for the oval for the arc to be drawn
            int left = px - radius;
            int top = py - radius;
            int right = left + (radius * 2);
            int bottom = top + (radius * 2);

            RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

                //canvas.rotate(25,px,py);//Rotate call -a

        canvas.drawArc(rectF, 0, 50, true, paint);

            canvas.rotate(25,px,py);//Rotate call  -b

        }
}
```

But if i place the rotate call(//Rotate call  -a) before drawing the arc i see that the arc drawn is shifted by 25 degrees more .What exactly is happening here? Can someone explain to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `Canvas` maintains a `Matrix` that is responsible for all transformations on it. Even for rotation. As you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#rotate%28float,%20float,%20float%29), the `rotate` method says:

`Preconcat the current matrix with the specified rotation.`

All transformations are done on the `Canvas` `Matrix`,hence, on the `Canvas`. The arc you draw isn't rotated. You first rotate the `Canvas` and then draw on it.

Hence, in your code, `call -a` works, not `call -b`.

EDIT:
For issues like postrotate and prerotate check the [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) class(`postRotate` and `preRotate` methods).

Few Examples: [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-canvas-your-android-apps-part-2) and [this](http://eleanordarephdjournal.blogspot.in/2011/03/another-good-android-example-with.html).

And few things you might want to read : [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8712652/rotating-image-on-a-canvas-in-android) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855578/android-matrix-what-is-the-different-between-preconcat-and-postconcat).

Comment: Thanks for the answer .But again the rotation would be applied to matrix even if i call it after drawing the arc.so shouldn't the whole arc be rotated.Am i missing something else here.If possible can you guide me to some reference on canvas drawing .(Have already read the android developer site)