# code to rotate image captured by camera intent not working in Android

Tags: android, image, rotation, image-rotation, android-camera-intent

I have a problem that my image captured using camera intent gets rotated, which I asked at [Why does an image captured using camera intent gets rotated on some devices on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android)

So as per the suggested answers there, I'm now trying to rotate the image which I get using camera(I have used camera intent). My code is,

```
public class SimpleCameraActivity extends Activity {
private static final int TAKE_PICTURE = 1888;
private Uri imageUri;
ImageView imageView;
Bitmap bitmap;
Button btnOK, btnDiscard;
RelativeLayout rLButtons;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_camera);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view_sc);
    captureImage();
}

public void captureImage() {
    Intent intentCamera = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File filePhoto = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pic.jpg");
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(filePhoto);
    MyApplicationGlobal.imageUri = imageUri.getPath();
    intentCamera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intentCamera, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intentFromCamera) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intentFromCamera);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE) {
        if (intentFromCamera != null) {
            Bundle extras = intentFromCamera.getExtras();
            if (extras.containsKey("data")) {
                bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            } else {
                bitmap = getBitmapFromUri();
            }
        } else {
            bitmap = getBitmapFromUri();
        }
        checkForRotation();
        //rotateImage();
        //rotateImage1();
        rotateImage3();
        //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        // imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}

public void rotateImage() {
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 80, bitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(180, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
    matrix.setRotate(90);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public void rotateImage1() {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate(90, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    matrix.mapRect(rectF);
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) rectF.width(), (int) rectF.height(), bitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, new Paint());
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public void rotateImage2() {
    Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
    mtx.reset();
    mtx.preTranslate(20, 30);
    mtx.setRotate((float) 90, 25, 35);
    mtx.postTranslate(30, 40);
    Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, 100, 100, mtx, true);
    this.bitmap = rotatedBMP;
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public void rotateImage3() {
    Bitmap bmpOriginal = bitmap;
    Bitmap targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((bmpOriginal.getWidth()), (bmpOriginal.getHeight()), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setAntiAlias(true);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.setRotate((float) 90, (float) (bmpOriginal.getWidth() / 2), (float) (bmpOriginal.getHeight() / 2));

    RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, bmpOriginal.getWidth(), bmpOriginal.getHeight());
    matrix.mapRect(rectF);

    targetBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) rectF.width(), (int) rectF.height(), Bitmap.Config.ALPHA_8);

    Canvas tempCanvas = new Canvas(targetBitmap);
    tempCanvas.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, matrix, p);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bmpOriginal);
}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromUri() {
    getContentResolver().notifyChange(imageUri, null);
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    Bitmap bitmap;
    try {
        bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, imageUri);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I have tried different codes rotateImage, 1, 2, 3 etc. But no code is working. rotateImage2() is working, but its badly affecting the quality, so can't use that.

I got these code from [Android: How to rotate a bitmap on a center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point) and there users say that its working, but not with me.
So what wrong I'm doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stick with *rotateImage2()* and use less transformations. This code works for me:

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(String pathToImage) {

    // 1. figure out the amount of degrees
    int rotation = getImageRotation();

    // 2. rotate matrix by postconcatination
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(rotation);

    // 3. create Bitmap from rotated matrix
    Bitmap sourceBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathToImage);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, sourceBitmap.getWidth(), sourceBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);        
}
```

To get the image rotation [check out your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066038/why-image-captured-using-camera-intent-gets-rotated-on-some-devices-in-android). For more infos on Matrix operations and their differences, e.g setRotate and postRotate [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855578/android-matrix-what-is-the-different-between-preconcat-and-postconcat).

Comment: BitmapFactory.decodeFile("my image path")(here imageUri) always returning null, but the good news is the code is rotating the image(bitmap)

Comment: Glad that it works for you, too. If "decodeFile" returns null, you probably got something wrong in your path: either the specified file name is null, or it cannot be decoded into a bitmap...