# Android: difference between preRotate and postRotate?

Tags: android, rotation, translation, transformation

What is the difference between preRotate and postRotate?

If I do every translation using postTranslate with preRotate the image, does that mean the image will do all the rotation first before translation. If I wanted to translate an image then rotate the image by its origin of the image. This way will work right...

If I use a postRotate instead of preRotate, I need to move the image back , rotate the postTranslate the image back to the location.

Am my right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855578/android-matrix-what-is-the-different-between-preconcat-and-postconcat)

Comment: This may be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855578/android-matrix-what-is-the-different-between-preconcat-and-postconcat/5123755