# Using an ImageView transform matrix instead of canvas.scale(float, float, float, float)

Tags: android, matrix, android-imageview, android-canvas

I need to change the way I am scaling and moving my imageview to using a matrix instead of calling `canvas.scale(,,,,)`, but I cannot figure out the proper calls to do this.

**I had** this in my `ScaleListener` listener class's `onScale` method

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {

    ...//determining zoom level and pivot points offset

    child.zoom(scaleFactor, zoomCenter[0], zoomCenter[1]);
}
```

**I had** in the child ImageView's `onDraw` method:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mPosX, mPosY);
    ...
    //do all the drawing here
}

public void zoom(float scaleFactor, float zoomCenterX, float zoomCenterY) {
    mScaleFactor = scaleFactor;
    mPosX = zoomCenterX;
    mPosY = zoomCenterY;

    //redraw and remeasure the mapview after zooming in
    invalidate();

}
```

I would like something like this in the `onScale` method:

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        ...//calculating scale and offsets

        Matrix m = child.getImageMatrix();
        m.reset();
        m.postScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        m.postTranslate(zoomCenter[0], zoomCenter[1]);
        child.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
        child.setImageMatrix(m);

        child.invalidate();


        return true;
    }
```

But this does not appear to be doing anything...am I missing something here? I tried using `child.getMatrix()` instead but that through an IllegalStateException saying the matrix cannot be modified. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured out what the problem was. I was using `setImageMatrix(m)` to apply to the entire ImageView child class, instead of setting the matrix for the canvas, like this:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    ...
    canvas.concat(transform);
```

}

I'm not sure what the difference is between the two though, if anyone knows see [difference bewteen imageMatrix and matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408401/what-is-the-difference-between-view-getmatrix-and-imageview-getimagematrix)

**EDIT**: using `canvas.setMatrix(transform)` messed up the scrolling; `canvas.concat(transform)` was recommended instead and that does this trick

Answer (score 0):

What if you try?

```
m.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
m.postTranslate(zoomCenter[0], zoomCenter[1]);
```

I also believe `child.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX)` is not needed. At least my coding works without it.

Comment: what is the difference between postScale() and setScale()? Also, I noticed there is a setScale(float, float, float, float) that i can use that does basically the same thing. But with the code I have above, nothing is updating

Comment: As I understand it, "post" is the last operation applied to the matrix. It can be only one "post" operation.

Comment: This questions has nice answer that cleared up the difference for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855578/android-matrix-what-is-the-different-between-preconcat-and-postconcat