# What is the difference between View.getMatrix() and ImageView.getImageMatrix()?

Tags: android, matrix, imageview, android-imageview

I'm guessing one of those is used to draw with a certain rotation, skew, scale, etc. like a transform matrix and the other one is used to map points like from one coordinate system to another (due to scaling, etc.)

Is correct? Which one does what?