# how to merge two images and create an anaglyph image in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, camera

I want to create an anaglyph image using 2 images taken from mobile camera. After the two images has been taken, I need to create a new image such that each New_Pixel = green_component_left_image+yello_component_right_image.

I searched lot and I can do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11740362/merge-two-bitmaps-in-android) but I want like [this video](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.suto.stereoroidpro&hl=en)

Thanks.

Comment: You must realize that the most intriguing part of 3DSteroid app is how to automatically arrange the two snapshots. The video shows that the end-user can edit the relative position of the overlapping pictures, including rotation and shift. But really to make this appealing, you would employ the accelerometer to adjust the inclination and probably some optical flow image tracking to estimate the movement.

Comment: @Alex Thanks for reply... Yeh.I have to use accelerometer for those lines. Can you suggest me regarding `The video shows that the end-user can edit the relative position of the overlapping pictures, including rotation and shift`

Comment: "edit the relative position of the overlapping pictures, including rotation and shift" - that's a completely different question. Essentially, you can keep the first image fixed, and manipulate the second, using the canvas transform (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408122/using-an-imageview-transform-matrix-instead-of-canvas-scalefloat-float-float)